# Returning yield of lambda within iter

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, yield

```
f=open('C:\\Python33\\text file.txt','r')

for c in iter(lambda: f.read(1),'\n'):
    print(?)
```

How would I print out the values which `lambda: f.read(1)` yields please?

Comment: What have you tried? What is in `text file.txt`? What are you expecting `f.read(1)` to give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just print the `c`. That's what you're getting from `iter()` in your for loop.

```
f=open('C:\\Python33\\text file.txt','r')

for c in iter(lambda: f.read(1),'\n'):
    print(c)
```

Small improvement suggestion, use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)-statement:

```
with open('C:\\Python33\\text file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for c in iter(lambda: f.read(1), '\n'):
        print(c)
```

This way you won't have to call `f.close()`.